# Contact Form 7 Checkbox's Want to align as 33 rows of 3

Tags: css

Have a Contact Form 7 page with 99 Checkbox’s
Want to align as 33 rows of 3

The Below CSS does that, but screws up Radio Buttons also.

```
.wpcf7-list-item {
width: 33% !important;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

What CSS can we use to only alter Checkbox’s?

https://srpds.com/sectione/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using:

```css
.wpcf7-checkbox .wpcf7-list-item {
    width: 33% !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```